# Flexbox in Safari wrapping not working as expected

Tags: css, safari, sass, cross-browser, flexbox

I have a product grid layout using flexbox. I would like this to show a minimum of two products in a row, no matter how small the screen is. I have the following code, which works in Chrome:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title that is longer than others</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
    <div class="product">
    <a href="javascript:void();">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="" />
    <p class="title">Product Title</p>
    </a>
    <p class="price">£100.00</p>
    <input class="small" value="Add to cart" type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS** (required prefixes added by Autoprefixer)

```
body {
  padding-top: 24px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.product {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 240px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .price {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  p {
    line-height: 24px;
  }
}
```

Codepen of the above is here:

http://s.codepen.io/mikehdesign/debug/bgKyop/vPrKKdOWoEEr

With this code I would expect to see 4 products in a row on large screens, reducing to two as a minimum on small screens. This is how it is working on Chrome, but on Safari I am seeing two products in a row at all screen sizes.

If I remove `flex-basis` from `.product` then I get 4 products in a row on large screens, but this drops down to 1 on small screens which is not what I want.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening in Safari, and how I can get the minimum of two products per row to work?

Answer (score 0):

Safari does have issues with calculating `flex-wrap` when using `min-width` which requires you to use `flex-basis` to communicate the width of the element. (This bug has finally been addressed for the next release of Safari)

I would recommend you set add `min-width` to `.product` unless that isn't the desired look you're going for.

Otherwise you need to set `flex-basis: 25%;` and then use a media-query for the size where there should only be 2 products to `flex-basis: 50%;`

http://codepen.io/Dreith/pen/ZLjWWe